# jquery change font-size based on value?

Tags: jquery, font-size

I have html:

```
<div class="arrow-inner arrow-first arrow-border">
 CAREER <strong>1.000</strong>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function battingAve1000(){
    var maxBatAve = "1.000";
    var batAve = $(".arrow-first strong").html();

    if(maxBatAve == batAve)
        $(".arrow-first strong").css('font-size', 20);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work?  Not sure why, seems right...

Comment: I would recommend for you to install and learn to use some sort of JavaScript debugger, allowing you to set a break point and examine the two variables compared in line #5. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a fantastic Firefox extension including JS debugger. Chrome comes with some niftly tools out of the box.

Comment: After doing a bit of debugging, you will most likely figure out the answer yourself. If not, you will be able to come back here and ask maybe "why does '1.000' == '1.000' yield false" or, "why doesn't .css('font-size', 20) change the font size", which are both much more better questions :)

Comment: i guess my problem is, it does work.  When I insert an alert after the if statement it alerts, but does not change my font-size in my css....which is why i'm confused.

Comment: Your code works exactly as written in chrome.  What browser and version of jquery are you using?  http://jsfiddle.net/LWgCD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
function battingAve1000(){
var maxBatAve = "1.000";
var batAve = $(".arrow-first").find('strong').html();
console.log($(".arrow-first").find('strong').html())
if(maxBatAve == batAve)
    $(".arrow-first").find('strong').css('font-size', 20);}
```

But yes check out firebug for firefox and learn about console.log() to see what your vars are returning.

Actually your code does work, you just didn't call the function perhaps? See this  http://jsfiddle.net/FWPd2/